# NSFetchRequestController works on iOS5, crash on iOS4.3

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios4, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have been trying to implement Core Data in a project that requires minimum of iOS 4.3. I get the code to work without any problems on iOS 5, but when trying it with iOS 4.3 it crashes with the following reason:

```
Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134060 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134060.)" UserInfo=0x4fb59b0 {reason=The fetched object at index 4 has an out of order section name 'Å. Objects must be sorted by section name'}, {
reason = "The fetched object at index 4 has an out of order section name '\U00c5. Objects must be sorted by section name'";
```

Here is my code:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
if (__fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return __fetchedResultsController;
}

// Set up the fetched results controller.
// Create the fetch request for the entity.
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
// Edit the entity name as appropriate.

fetchRequest.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Exhibitor" 
                                  inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

// Edit the sort key as appropriate.
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" 
                                                               ascending:YES 
                                                                selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

// Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
// nil for section name key path means "no sections".
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] 
                                                         initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                         managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext 
                                                         sectionNameKeyPath:@"firstLetter" 
                                                         cacheName:nil];
aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

NSError *error = nil;
if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    /*
     Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

     abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
     */
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}

  return __fetchedResultsController;
}
```

If I in my sortDesctriptor choose to use caseInsensitivecompare: instead of localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare: it doesn't crash but the order is wrong (since I need Å Ä Ö to be at the bottom, not after A and O).

Suggestions?

**UPDATE:**
Seems like when I kill my app in the multitasking bar and then relaunch it, the order with ÅÄÖ is correct (using caseInsensitiveCompare). But only after first relaunch. It is still wrong at first launch...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using section index titles? That seems what this error is referring to.

Simply add:

```
-(NSString *)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
             sectionIndexTitleForSectionName:(NSString *)sectionName {
   return sectionName;
}
```

to your table view controller.

Comment: That didn't actually solve the problem with localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare BUT it did solve the wrong order with caseInsensitiveCompare. So thats a win! Since my app is only localized in Swedish anyway it seems to solve itself. Thanks.